# visible gap between anchors

Tags: html, css

I can't get rid of visible gaps between anchors in my navigation menu. I tried everything with padding, margin and width in nav ul and nav li, but the nav li color is still visible. How can I stretch the red color to the full width of the single anchor?

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px; 
    background-color: rgb(237, 215, 213);
    border-bottom: 2px solid black; 
    border-left: 2px solid black;   
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
  
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

nav li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">DESCRIPTION</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">HISTORY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">LIVE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">GALLERY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix is to apply `display: flex;` also to the `ul` element. Otherwise (as you experienced)  the linebreaks in the code cause those spaces.

(You could also remove the linebreaks in the code instead of applying flex, but that's more work...)

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(237, 215, 213);
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

nav li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="">DESCRIPTION</a></li>
    <li><a href="">HISTORY</a></li>
    <li><a href="">LIVE</a></li>
    <li><a href="">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```